# SplitView delegate not set using segue replace master split

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

My question is regarding a `UISplitView` based application in iOS SDK5.1.

- The app is splitview based.
- Everything is working fine when stating the app, while the root master- and detail views are used.
- Later on, I segue master- and detail view, using segue type: "replace master split"

Here is where the trouble starts:

- If all the above happened in portrait mode, the bar button to show the master view is not shown.
- Turning to landscape mode and back cures the issue.

The masterVC sets itself as `splitview.delegate` in `-(void)viewDidLoad`, which I suspect is too late, thus the delegate methods can not be called in time.

So I tried to set the delegate in `-(void)prepareForSegue`..., which didn´t change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Set the UISplitViewController delegate in your App Delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
 UITableViewController *yourViewController = (UITableViewController*)[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
splitViewController.delegate = yourViewController;

 }
```

Make sure that yourViewController conforms to the UISplitViewControllerDelegate protocol.

Edit: Also, if your MasterViewController is embedded in a navigation controller you're going to have to access it by accessing the UINavigationController first then accessing it's topViewController.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Tried this, did not change the behavior, which makes sense imo, as it doesn´t influence later assingments in my understanding. It also conforms the UISplitViewControllerDelegate protocol. It´s actually working, but not on the first load.

Comment: Funny: I just tried not to set the delegate anywhere (not in MasterVC and not in AppDelegate) and the behaviour is still the same. ??

Comment: What happens when you use the detail VC as the SPVC delegate? In my experience setting the MasterVC as the delegate has led to trouble.

Comment: Setting the detailVC as SPVC delegate did not do the trick neither. I still suspect, when replacing the detailVC via "segue replace detail", the delegate is set too late somehow.